# Plus quantifier does not check the last character if last character has negated set

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I need to match a string with the following constraints:

1. At least one alphanumeric character
2. Forbid specific characters (^*@:;)
3. Forbid dot at the end

I have the next pattern:

```
^[^*@:;]*[\p{Alnum}]+[^*@:;]*[^.*@:;]$
```

The problem is that when I have an alphanumeric character at the end, the string will not match the pattern.

For example:

`$$$....1$` will match the pattern.

`$$$....$1` will not.

As far as I understand, the problem is that `[\p{Alnum}]+` does not check the last character.

Is there any possible way to do this with one regexp?

Comment: Try this: `^(?=[^*@:;]*[a-zA-Z\d])[^^*@:;]*[^^.*@:;]$`

Comment: kind of correct, the problem is that `[^.*@:;]$` is the last character, so the `[\p{Alnum}]+` does not have anything left to match (in second example `$$$...$` has no 'Alnum' to match) (try without that last `[^.*@:;]` and add a negative look-behind for dot)

Comment: What is the current problem? Are you testing the pattern at some online regex testing site and it does not work? Negated character classes match line breaks, so you may not be getting the correct testing results, all you need is add `\n` there. Also, if you need to avoid matching a `^` char, toy need to add `^` to your negated character classes. Check if `^[^^*@:;\n]*\p{Alnum}[^^*@:;\n]*[^^.*@:;\n]$` works for you. See https://regex101.com/r/mCsinY/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the following should tick your boxes:

```
^(?=.*\p{Alnum})(?!.*[*@:;]).+(?<!\.)$
```

Where:

- `^` - Start string anchor.
- `(?=.*\p{Alnum})` - Postive lookahead to match at least a single alphanumeric character.
- `(?!.*[*@:;])` - Negative lookahead to prevent any of the characters mentioned in the character class.
- `.+` - 1+ characters other than newline.
- `(?<!\.)` - Negative lookbehind to prevent a dot before;
- `$` - End string anchor.

See the online [demo](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyydw95war)

---

Alternatively use a negated character class as you were doing instead of the negative lookahead:

```
^(?=.*\p{Alnum})[^*@:;\n]+(?<!\.)$
```

- `^` - Start string anchor.
- `(?=.*\p{Alnum})` - Postive lookahead to match at least a single alphanumeric character.
- `[^*@:;\n]+` - 1+ characters other than those mentioned in the character class.
- `(?<!\.)` - Negative lookbehind to prevent a dot before;
- `$` - End string anchor.

See the online [demo](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyydve44nr)

Comment: Note: start/end anchor not needed if using `matches()` (and additional +1 (if I could) for using an online engine that supports Java regex)